# jquery toggle individual list item

Tags: jquery, list

I am using the function below to toggle comment boxes in an activity feed. What should happen is that the word "Comment" is clicked and the comment box becomes visible.

This is only happening for the first element in the list. If I click on the word "Comment" on any entry besides the first, the first comment_box toggles.

How can I get each comment box to toggle individually? Also, what is this issue called in jQuery? I tried to look it up but didn't know what to call it.

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

    $('span#comment_box').hide();

    $('.comment').click(function() {

    $('#comment_box').toggle();

    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<span href="" class="comment">Comment</span><br />
    <span id="comment_box"><textarea name="status_comment"  /></textarea><br /></span>
```

Here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jpBE3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the `id` should be unique for each element on the page. May be you have multiple elements with same id so you are facing this issue. jQuery will return the first element which has the required id when you use `$('#comment_box')`.

Instead of id I would suggest you use class and then you can select the element by its class name. You have to use `nextAll` passing the required selector to find the corresponding element and the call toggle method on it.

**Markup change**

```
<span href="" class="comment">Comment</span><br />
<span class="comment_box"><textarea name="status_comment"  /></textarea><br /></span>
```

**JS**

```
  $(function(){
       $('span.comment_box').hide();
       $('.comment').click(function() {
           $(this).nextAll('.comment_box:first').toggle();
       });
  });
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this).nextAll('.comment_box').first().toggle();` just use `$(this).next('.comment_box').toggle();`. `next()` only returns one element making the subsequent `first()` unnecessary.

Comment: @Jordan - `next` will only look in the immediate sibling, if the selector matches it will return or else no. It do not go further down checking in all the siblings. Take a look http://api.jquery.com/next/. In my answer I can combine `:first` with the selector and avoid `first` method call.

Comment: This isn't working on my site. I've changed comment_box to a class and when I click Comment, all the comments show. How can I get one comment_box to show at a time? (I've got an activity feed that's running a phpforeach function).

Comment: It should work fine if your markup is correct. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/zCyFw/, it finds only one element.

Comment: The markup is fine. If I use $('.comment_box').toggle(); in the click function, if I click Comment, I get all the comments showing. If I use $(this).nextAll('.comment_box:first').toggle(); in the click function, if I click on Comment, nothing happens.

Comment: Try this `$(this).nextAll('.comment_box').first().toggle();`

Comment: I tried it; still not working. I setup a jsfiddle with your code and it works there, but on my page it doesn't even fire (but the other toggle function I mention does fire). Is there any other way to get the click function to apply only the clicked comment?

Comment: It's way too extensive. I'll accept your answer because it works in the jsfiddle and figure it out myself. But I am concerned that it doesn't even fire and the other toggle function does.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have more the one elements with the id comment_box .... css ids should be unique on a page. That's why it toggles the first comment_box because it should only be 1 element with the id comment_box on a page. Use class instead of id.

Comment: I'm using class now and when I click Comment, all comments open. Any idea how to toggle one comment box at a time?

Comment: Use the javascript provided by ShankarSangoli   ...above.